# Magento 2 : Remove Address Book from customer Dashboard

Tags: magento-2.1, customer, customer-account

i want to remove **Address Book Block** from customer dashboard

i did tried below code but it seems not working

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve by removing the block from customer_account_index.xml

Create **customer_account_index.xml** layout file in your custom module or theme directory and add below code:

```
<referenceBlock name="customer_account_dashboard_address" remove="true" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a `customer_account_index.xml` inside `Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_index.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <referenceBlock name="customer_account_dashboard_address" remove="true" />
        </referenceContainer>

    </body>
</page>
```

And if you want to remove **Unwanted Navigation tab links** from Customer account dashboard
Create a file `customer_account.xml` inside `Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/customer_account.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <body>
        
            <!-- Remove unwanted account navigation links -->

            <!-- Store credit -->

            <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-customer-balance-link" remove="true"/>

            <!-- Downloadable product link -->

            <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-downloadable-products-link" remove="true"/>

            <!-- Subscription link -->

            <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-newsletter-subscriptions-link" remove="true"/>

            <!-- Billing agreement link -->

            <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-billing-agreements-link" remove="true"/>

            <!-- Product review link -->

            <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-product-reviews-link" remove="true"/>

            <!-- My credit card link -->

            <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-my-credit-cards-link" remove="true"/>

            <!-- Account link -->

            <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-account-link" remove="true"/>

            <!-- Account edit link -->

            <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-account-edit-link" remove="true"/>

            <!-- Address link -->

            <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-address-link" remove="true"/>

            <!-- Orders link -->

            <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-orders-link" remove="true"/>

            <!-- Wish list link -->

            <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-wish-list-link" remove="true"/>

            <!-- Gift card link -->

            <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-gift-card-link" remove="true"/>

            <!-- Order by SKU -->

            <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-checkout-sku-link" remove="true"/>

            <!-- Gift registry -->

            <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-giftregistry-link" remove="true"/>

            <!-- Reward points -->

            <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-reward-link" remove="true"/>
        
        </body>
</page>
```